# Symfony2.8 website(SP) & OKTA(IDP)

Tags: symfony, okta, simplesamlphp

I've created the membership website with Symfony2. I used FOSuserbundle for the website.

Then I'm trying to setup the IDP initiated single sign on environment with this website and OKTA, but I have a situation here with the SP side settings.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0Jia.gif)

I can see the posted SAML with Firefox SAML tracer after doing No.4(attached image) process, but authentication will be failed.

The list is below what I did.

**step1**

Getting okta-simplesamlphp-example to set up the SimpleSAMLphp

https://github.com/jpf/okta-simplesamlphp-example

saml-autoconfig.php

```
$metadata_url_for = array(
     'example' => 'ttps://xxxxxx.com/app/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/sso/saml/metadata',
);
```

**step2**

To setup OKTA

> Single sign on URL

ttp://xxxxxxxx.com/simplesamlphp/www/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-acs.php/example

> Audience URI (SP Entity ID)

ttp://xxxxxxxx.com/simplesamlphp/www/module.php/saml/sp/metadata.php/example

> Default RelayState

ttps://xxxx.okta.com/app/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxwebsite_1/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/sso/saml

(I found the url by clicking "View Setup Instructions" on the Sign On tab for the application in the admin console)

**step3**

instaling SamlBundle for the membership website

ttps://github.com/pdias/SamlBundle

I think I'm missing a connection between website and SimpleSAMLphp. How can I connect each other?

Any help here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix this problem!

I made mistakes with the SamlBundle settings.

```
# UserBundle\Resources\config\services.xml

<service id="saml.backend.fosuser.provider" class="UserBundle\Security\User\FosBackendSamlUserProvider">
    <argument type="service" id="samlauth.service"/>
    <argument type="service" id="fos_user.user_manager"/>
</service>
```

this one is the example code, but in my case should have been like...

```
  <services>
<service id="saml.backend.fosuser.provider" class="FOS\UserBundle\Security\User\FosBackendSamlUserProvider">
    <argument type="service" id="samlauth.service"/>
    <argument type="service" id="fos_user.user_manager"/>
</service>
```

The class URL should have changed.

Also I made a mistake with OKTA's Default RelayState.

It is just home URL like "http://xxxxxxxxxx.com/".

"OKTA + simplesamlPHP + symfony2.8(with fosuserbundle) + pdias/SamlBundle"

This combination is working now.

Comment: Default RelayState is not home URL now. Blank is fine.